# Vertical scrolling for multiple div tags inside a div tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a scrollable file tree. Minimal code can be found below.

https://jsfiddle.net/3kLmchot/1/

Problem is when I try to add `overflow-y: scroll;`, to the `filebrowse-outer` div, the first few items are not visible at all. This problem gets worse when I add more divs.

It seems like items are added about the center of the `filebrowse-outer` div, so the items that are added at the bottom can be found via scrolling, but the items that are added at the top are invisible. (see the visual aid below)

```
item 1  
item 2  
center of the div  
item 3  
item 4
```

Scroll bar forms at around item 2, which makes item 1 invisible. Does anyone know why this is happening, and potential solutions?

Comment: ive always had problems with flex and not giving outer a height

Comment: Currently, I gave height property to "side-bar" (the outermost container). Also, giving height to "filebrowse-outer" instead of "side-bar" does not seem to improve the situation...

Comment: i got it to work by .flex-container { display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following styles, specifically removing `justify-content: center;` from your `.flex-container` that is being used by multiple divs and only applying it to the one that is for `.flex-container.filebrowse-inner`

```
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
/*   justify-content: center;  <-- THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ISSUE */ 
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container.filebrowse-outer {
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container.filebrowse-inner {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

/* .display-container {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: auto;   
} */
```

Comment: can't believe I couldn't figure out something so simple even after spending a few hours lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you meant to have scroll bar in the external div with class 'side-bar', if yes:

```css
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.flex-container.filebrowse-outer {
 flex-direction: column;
 border: solid;
    min-height: max-content; /* For safari*/
 /* overflow-y: scroll; */
 align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container.filebrowse-inner {
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 100%;
    min-height: max-content; /* For safari*/
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
}

.display-container {
 width: 70%;
 overflow: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="flex-container filebrowse-outer">
    <div class="flex-container filebrowse-inner">
      <div class="display">
        <p>Click Me 1!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container filebrowse-inner">
      <div class="display">
        <p>Click Me 2!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container filebrowse-inner">
      <div class="display">
        <p>Click Me 3!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container filebrowse-inner">
      <div class="display">
        <p>Click Me 4!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then move the border to 'side-bar' class.